# How to set the queue number and size for a FreeBSD bridge?

Tags: queue, switch-statement, freebsd, bridge

I am using FreeBSD as a "switch" connecting multiple interfaces.
I am interested how to set the queue number and size (in bytes) for each switch port. Unfortunately, I did not find any hint how to accomplish it.

Thanks.
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of would be driver-specific tunables that control number of RX/TX descriptors.For instance, Intel drivers allow setting it via following tunables in loader.conf:

- em: hw.em.rxd, hw.em.txd
- igb: hw.igb.rxd, hw.igb.txd

Specific tunables are often described in the corresponding man page.

Also, depending on what and how you're switching, you may want to adjust 
net.inet.ip.intr_queue_maxlen sysctl.